# How can I delete a specific column in a tab seperated csv?

Tags: pandas, csv

I found some code online that deletes a specific column by name using pandas:

```
# import pandas with shortcut 'pd'
import pandas as pd  
  
# read_csv function which is used to read the required CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('TradedInstrument_20230331_test.csv')
  
  
# drop function which is used in removing or deleting rows or columns from the CSV files
data.drop('isin', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Any ideas if this actually works for a tab seperated csv?

If I run the above against my file, I get a UnicodeDecodeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ....
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1917, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 38835: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an encoding error. It looks like `0xfc` is `ü` character (*latin small letter u with diaeresis*), so try to use `encoding='latin1'` when your read your csv file:

```
data = pd.read_csv('TradedInstrument_20230331_test.csv', sep='\t', encoding='latin1')
data.drop(columns='isin').to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: This works thank you! 

Also, it doesn't autmatically save down, how can I save the document?

Comment: I assume it didn't save because although the code ran ok no changes were made in the file.

Comment: @Patrick_Chong. I updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing, is it possible to save it down as a `.txt` format?